# Traversing/Moving over an unfolded cube

Tags: algorithm, 3d

After creating a cube with vertices where each face is its own set of vertices, I want to be able to add to a current 2d position, which is a point on a face of the cube.Lets say the current point is A(5,3) on the front face and then it's being modified by (+5, +0). Depending on how you unfold the cube it might be different but lets say the first 4 faces are left, front, right and back each with a width of 8 vertices. After applying the modification on point A that is currently on the front face, it's position would change to (10,3) and then would overflow to the next face at point (2,3) after we subtract the difference and consider that the vertices from each face on the edges would overlap. I get that I can calculate this out for each face and even combine some calculations together to limit redundant code, but I am really looking for a more elegant solution that doesn't require so many conditions, like which face the vertex is currently on and then potentially 4 conditions for each of the 6 faces to determine where the overflow happens.

Essentially I am creating a cube like below that is unwrapped, where the lines are connecting each cube. Lets say this cube has 5 * 5 vertices per face. Lets say the currently selected index is 8 on the front square of the cube. That would be the coordinates of (3,1) on that cube. If I want to move to the next point on the right it would be (4,1) and then (5,1). Lets say then I want to move onto the next vertex to the right, which would be (1,1) (it's 1,1 and not 0,1 since the edges of the vertices are duplicated) on the square to the right of the front face. The way I am doing it now is I have multiple conditions based on the square that the origin point is, and then determining where the point would be on the adjacent square. This is a lot of conditions, technically 4 conditions for 6 faces (which can be less depending on how the cube is built or indexed), and I am just looking for a more elegant solution.

[image]

edit:
Here is how I am calculating the cube

```
        Vertices = new Vector3[size * size * 6];

        float vertexSpacing = 1.0f / ((float)size - 1.0f);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size*size*6; i++)
        {
            int faceNumber = i / (size * size);
            int gridI = i - (faceNumber * size * size);
            int gridX = gridI % (size);
            int gridY = gridI / (size);
            
            //Console.WriteLine("Actual I: " + i + " | GridX: " + gridX + " | GridY: " + gridY );
            
            float x;
            float y;
            float z;
            
            if (faceNumber == 0) //left face
            {
                x = -0.5f;
                y = -0.5f + (gridY * vertexSpacing);
                z = -0.5f + (gridX * vertexSpacing);
                //Console.WriteLine("Grid XY: {0}, {1} | Grid Index: {2} | Actual Index: {3}", gridX, gridY, gridI, i);

            } else if (faceNumber == 1) //front face
            {
                x = -0.5f + (gridX * vertexSpacing);
                y = -0.5f + (gridY * vertexSpacing);
                z = 0.5f;
            } else if (faceNumber == 2) //right face
            {
                x = 0.5f;
                y = -0.5f + (gridY * vertexSpacing);
                z = 0.5f - (gridX * vertexSpacing);
            }  else if (faceNumber == 3) //back face
            {
                x = 0.5f - (gridX * vertexSpacing);
                y = -0.5f + (gridY * vertexSpacing);
                z = -0.5f;
            } else if (faceNumber == 4) //top Face
            {
                x = -0.5f + (gridX * vertexSpacing);
                y = 0.5f;
                z = 0.5f - (gridY * vertexSpacing);
            } else //bottom face
            {
                x = -0.5f + (gridX * vertexSpacing);
                y = -0.5f;
                z = -0.5f + (gridY * vertexSpacing);
            }
            
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x,y,z);

            float x2 = pos.X * pos.X;
            float y2 = pos.Y * pos.Y;
            float z2 = pos.Z * pos.Z;

            Vector3 s = new Vector3
            {
                X = pos.X * (float)Math.Sqrt(1f - y2 / 2f - z2 / 2f + y2 * z2 / 3f),
                Y = pos.Y * (float)Math.Sqrt(1f - z2 / 2f - x2 / 2f + x2 * z2 / 3f),
                Z = pos.Z * (float)Math.Sqrt(1f - x2 / 2f - y2 / 2f + x2 * y2 / 3f)
            };

            s = s.Normalized();
            Vertices[i] = s * scale;
        }
```

The vertices are accessible easily by determining the face which would be
`index/(size * size)`
and then I can determine the the x's and y's or the index inside the face easily with something like
`x = index - face * (size * size) % size`
`y = index - face * (size * size) / size`
I can use these to apply offsets and to see if there would be an overflow on the x or y axis which I can then select the next square that the selection should move to.

My faces are set up with left, front, right, back, top, bottom being the order from 0 to 5.

So after seeing an overflow on the x axis for a face, I can determine which face is right of it or left of it and select that face as the new face and then just offset by the difference of the overflow to determine where the x should be on the face that the selection overflowed to (sometimes this requires swapping the x and y in a case similar to where the top face overflows it's x axis, it would overflow to the y axis of the right or left faces).

Overflowing both x and y is not a problem for what I need. If you think of this like selecting a range of points from a surface to get a "square/circle" within the surface that you can modify the vertices of, then at the corners where the x and y overflow, you just ignore the overflow of the other axis when you are selecting the new point on the new face. This works because if the selection is 5,5, it would also select everything in between that. Since it's accepting everything in between that, if it were to overflow with both the x and y, you can just process each axis separately and ignore the overflow on the second axis since they would just overlap after wrapping at the corners.

Here is an example of how I move the selection across the first 4 faces in case the selection goes over the X axis if that helps. I have different code for determining if it should go over the y axis and then code that also handles the top and bottom faces.

```
        int sourceFace = chunk.Face;
        int targetFace = -1;
        int segmentX = chunk.SegmentIndex % faceSize + (int)x;
        int segmentY = chunk.SegmentIndex / faceSize + (int)y;

        bool sideFace = (sourceFace < 4);


        if (sideFace)
        {
            if (segmentX < 0)
            {
                if (sourceFace == 3)
                    targetFace = 0;
                else
                    targetFace = sourceFace - 1;
                segmentX += faceSize;
            }
            if (segmentX >= faceSize)
            {
                if (sourceFace == 3)
                    targetFace = 0;
                else
                    targetFace = sourceFace + 1;
                segmentX -= faceSize;
            }

            if (segmentY < 0)
            {
                
            }

            if (segmentY > faceSize)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

What I am doing works as expected, but I am mainly just looking for a more elegant solution if anyone knows of one.

With what I am doing, there isn't a problem with selecting vertices when the x and y are greater than the size of the face. Normally it would be that you could end up on one of 2 faces depending on which you applied first, but I am only using this code in 2 situations. One where the direction is normalized and never multiplied so it will only ever move up to 2 points, if the x and y are either .5 or -.5 but then it will still end up on the same point, even if the face is different, because the faces have duplicated vertices at the edge. For the other way I am using this, it will be okay to ignore the difference from one axis since I am selecting an area around the point. Because of this, you can safely ignore one of the axes where both are greater than the width of the face, and it will only select up to the edge. This only happens at the corner, but again it still works for what I am doing as long as I ignore one axis after it's greater than the width because I'm selecting everything between it and the origin point. So the selection of 5,5 would be 5 up and 5 across, and everything in between that, meaning if it were at a corner, it would still select the correct vertices.

The kind of solution I was hoping to find would be something similar to the simple solution for rock paper scissors

```
    User = inputSomeInteger
    Comp = random.randint(0,2)
    winner = (Comp-User)%3
    winner 0 = tie, winner 1 = comp win, winner 2 = user win
```

Sure for this solution you could do a bunch of if's and else's outs of the three to determine the winner, but this is more elegant and efficient. I was wondering if there was something similar to this for an unfolded cube when traversing it

Comment: Please add the (minimum necessary) code for the creation of the cube, and your attempt at moving a point accros the faces.

Comment: The problem seems to be ill-formed.  If you modify a point by, say (5,5), you can end up on a different face depending on whether you do x or y first.

Comment: @trincot The code for the cube isn't necessary as I can calculate a cube in quite a few ways. The way I am calculating it now and storing it is to make the current algorithm I'm using the most efficient that I can think of. I'm sure the cube can be calculated differently if it's being used with a different algorithm but I'll add some more context to that anyway to see if that helps anyone understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, if you decide to not include your attempt, and the problem encountered, this question has no future.

Comment: @trincot My bad, I have the code and what I'm attempting outlined in my edited post

Comment: I get so far: https://go.dev/play/p/QwWmhyzOozG

Comment: @VonC that's very similar to my current solution and would require the same number of conditions if not more. I edited my post to help explain better the type of solution I am looking for

Comment: @servvs Something more like https://go.dev/play/p/htsFFMSzDdZ ?

Comment: @VonC That's still pretty similar to what I'm doing but I think it's helping me answer the question if there is a more efficient way. I think I'll go with this for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The kind of solution I was hoping to find would be something similar to the simple solution for rock paper scissors

The cube's geometry does not naturally lend itself to a cyclic group like in the rock-paper-scissors example, where operations loop back in a simple, circular manner. The cube's transitions are more complex due to its 3D nature and the different adjacency relationships between faces.

However, for specific movements like moving from one face to another in a predefined path (e.g., cycling through front, right, back, left, and then back to front), you can attempt a simplified model, where you would:

- assign numbers to the faces involved in the horizontal movement: 0 (Left), 1 (Front), 2 (Right), 3 (Back).
- define movement rules: Moving right increases the face number by 1, and moving left decreases the face number by 1. When the face number exceeds 3, it loops back to 0, and if it goes below 0, it loops back to 3.

For vertical movements (top to bottom or bottom to top) and handling edge wrapping (e.g., moving off the right edge of the right face to appear on the left face), you would need need additional logic since these movements involve changing both the face and the position (x, y coordinates) in a way that is not perfectly cyclical due to the geometry of the cube.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77970895/traversing-moving-over-an-unfolded-cube#comment137493983_77970895), my last iteration of code leads me ([playground for testing](https://go.dev/play/p/htsFFMSzDdZ)) to:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    faceWidth, faceHeight     = 5, 5
    canvasWidth, canvasHeight = faceWidth * 3, faceHeight * 3 // Adjusted for the cross pattern layout
)

// Cube represents the current state of a traversal on an unfolded cube.
type Cube struct {
    face     int // Current face
    x, y     int // Current position on the face
    faceSize int // Size of each face
}

// NewCube initializes a new cube with a specified face size.
func NewCube(faceSize int) *Cube {
    return &Cube{
        faceSize: faceSize,
    }
}

// SetPosition sets the starting position on the cube.
func (c *Cube) SetPosition(face, x, y int) {
    c.face = face
    c.x = x
    c.y = y
}

// Move simulates moving from the current position and handles face transitions.
// direction: 1 for right, -1 for left
func (c *Cube) Move(direction int) {
    c.x += direction

    if c.x < 0 {
        c.face = (c.face - 1 + 4) % 4
        c.x = c.faceSize - 1 // Wrap to the far right of the new face
    } else if c.x >= c.faceSize {
        c.face = (c.face + 1) % 4
        c.x = 0 // Start at the leftmost edge of the new face
    }

    fmt.Printf("Moved to face: %d, Position: (%d, %d)\n", c.face, c.x, c.y)
}

// Print displays the current state of the cube.
func (c *Cube) Print() {
    faceNames := []string{"Left", "Front", "Right", "Back"}
    fmt.Printf("Face: %s, Position: (%d, %d)\n", faceNames[c.face], c.x+1, c.y+1) // +1 for 1-based indexing
}

func (c *Cube) calculateFaceOffset() (int, int) {
    switch c.face {
    case 0: // Left face
        return 0, faceHeight
    case 1: // Front face
        return faceWidth, faceHeight
    case 2: // Right face
        return faceWidth * 2, faceHeight
    case 3: // Back face
        return faceWidth, faceHeight * 2
    default:
        return 0, 0
    }
}

func main() {
    cube := NewCube(5) // Initialize the cube with 5x5 vertices per face

    cube.SetPosition(1, 2, 1) // Starting at vertex index 8 on the front face (0-based indexing)
    fmt.Println("Starting State:")
    cube.Print()

    cube.Move(1) // Move right
    fmt.Println("After 1st Move (within the same face):")
    cube.Print()

    cube.Move(1) // Move right again, expecting a transition to the right face
    fmt.Println("After 2nd Move (transition to the right face):")
    cube.Print()
}
```